# How to get tensorflow c++ with opencl support on windows?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I need to compile tensorflow c++ in windows with GPU support but I can't use CUDA, so I opted in to using OpenCL. Many sources on the internet shows how to get the build for tensorflow python package. Other sources provide a linux solution. I might use WSL or sycl but those solutions still use the .so files and I want a .dll file.

So my question is: How do I get a tensorflow c++ build (tensorflow.dll) with OpenCL?